# Retrieving the line number from an Internet Explorer error object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a way to retrieve the line number from an Internet Explorer 7/8 error object?

I'm only aware of the .message, .description and .number properties.

I've searched around a bit and found an MSDN article on .stack ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699850(v=vs.94).aspx ), but even using their own example code doesn't return a line number:

http://jsfiddle.net/LWevS/

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506593/need-to-find-actual-location-of-line-char-in-internet-explorer-script-errors) help?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, I'm not setting up a debugger for dev purposes but rather once the code is in production. We'd like to be able to turn on JS error logging and  store line number back instead of just a description of the error.

Comment: You should perhaps edit your question to add that information, as it makes a difference in possible answers.

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, sorry, but I had to comment 'cause your name is eerily close to mine. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dug around some more and found that it is possible to retrieve the line number in IE using window.onerror. It's not from the Error object itself, but it's a decent workaround:

```
function BadFunction(){
    This.badcode.willnot.work = 1000
}

function ForceError(msg, url, lno) {
  alert("Error Occurred! Handled by Generic Error Handler" + "\n" +
     "Error: " + msg + "\n" + "URL: " + url + "\n" +   
     "Line Number: " + lno);

  return true;
}

window.onerror = ForceError;
```

This method requires that the error bubble up to the window. If you have a try/catch in your code, you will need to re-throw the error so it can bubble up.

I also came across StackTraceJS on GitHub while researching a solution to this problem. Their stack tracing script works great on all browsers except for Internet Explorer. A great run-time debugger if you want to log errors produced on the client browser.

http://stacktracejs.com/

Comment: How to re throw the error in try..catch! Can you please give an example!